# Blender is not responding after opening

Tags: interface

I'm having trouble working with Blender. I'm using Windows 10, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz 1.80 GHz processor, 8 GB RAM with Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 and Radeon(TM) 520 graphics cards. I installed Blender 3.0 and when opened it just flashed a white screen and disappeared. With versions 2.9, 2.8, and below, I was able to see the workspace, but after clicking on the options and objects, the screen froze and turned out to be "Not Responding". It would be very helpful if anybody could solve this issue. How can I use Blender stably in my system?